# Flex 4.12.0 setFocus fires click event

Tags: apache-flex, focus, enter, textinput, flex-spark

While migrating to new version of Flex SDK 4.12.0 (from version 4.6) I found a bug or at least an unfortunate feature. 
When passing the focus on component button, the button's click event is dispatched.

Required application state: If user (with actual focus in "tiTwo" text input) press the Enter key, focus is then passed on component button.
After pushing Enter on text input, click event must not be dispatched on "button".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="800" minHeight="600">  
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout gap="8" horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="20"/>
</s:layout>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent;

        // BUTTON click handler
        protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            status.text += "button CLICKED \n";
        }

        // TEXT INPUT focus out handler
        protected function ti_focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
        {
            status.text += "focusOut  " + event.currentTarget.id + "\n";
        }

        // TEXT INPUT key down handler (move focus to next focusable component)
        protected function ti_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            // temp solution - not good for bigger application
            //event.stopPropagation();
            //event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
                var focusableComponent:IFocusManagerComponent = focusManager
                       .getNextFocusManagerComponent();
                focusManager.setFocus(focusableComponent);

                // same problem (enter click dispatch...)
                //focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent().setFocus();
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>    
<s:Label id="introLabel" text="TAB vs ENTER test (Flex SDK 4.12.0)"
         color="0xDCDCDC" fontSize="18"/>

<!-- TI 1 -->
<s:TextInput id="tiOne" focusOut="ti_focusOutHandler(event)"
             keyDown="ti_keyDownHandler(event)" prompt="tiOne"/>
<!-- TI 2 -->
<s:TextInput id="tiTwo" focusOut="ti_focusOutHandler(event)"
             keyDown="ti_keyDownHandler(event)" prompt="tiTwo"/>    
<!-- BTN -->
<s:Button id="button" click="button_clickHandler(event)"
          label="BTN"/> 
<!-- TI 3 -->
<s:TextInput id="tiThree" focusOut="ti_focusOutHandler(event)"
             keyDown="ti_keyDownHandler(event)" prompt="tiThree"/>
<!-- TI 4 -->
<s:TextInput id="tiFour" focusOut="ti_focusOutHandler(event)"
             keyDown="ti_keyDownHandler(event)" prompt="tiFour"/>
<!-- TITLE -->
<s:Label id="title" text="Status:"
         color="0xDCDCDC" fontSize="14"/>
<!-- TEXT AREA -->
<s:TextArea id="status" height="400"
            editable="false" focusEnabled="false"/>
</s:Application>
```

How can I fix this error? This is happening in Flash Player 11.6.602.168 and Flash Player 13.0.0.182 (it is SDK problem), and same problem occurs with Apache SDK 4.11 or 4.12.1

Can be traced with 4.6 vs 4.12.0 (easy to reproduce -> **start example app, mouse click on tiOne, press Enter twice**)

```
4.6:
focusOut  tiOne
focusOut  tiTwo

4.12.0:
focusOut  tiOne
focusOut  tiTwo
button CLICKED
```

Comment: I think it is because you are using the Enter key, have you tried doing it with another key? I think that if you are focused on a button and press the enter key the click event is dispatched.

Comment: I need the focus to move/pass after press the enter key (when I'm in textinput).
If I'm on the button and press enter, the Click event is dispatched, that is alright.
But in this case the Click event is dispatched on the button while I **press the enter key in textinput**. See the example.
Try to run the above simple code please.

Comment: if you uncomment `//event.stopPropagation();` Does it still not work?

Comment: That works, but in a big application (in which this problem is fatal) stopping the propagation might ruin a lot of working things.
Many funcionalities are handled by FocusOut and Click event.
This is a last resort solution, which I want to avoid if possible.
This issue did not occur in v.4.6, the question is why does it occur in 4.12.0.

Comment: Then it must be a bug

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-34325